# How do we write Recursive function in SML?

Tags: sml, smlnj

Here is the python code for the recursive function I am implementing.

```
def f(x):
  return x+1
def iter(n, f,x):
  if n == 0:
    return x
  return iter(n-1, f, f(x))
```

Calling iter

```
iter(7, f, 9)
```

How do I write it in SML?

```
fun iter 0 f x = x
  |iter n f x = iter(n-1, f, f(x));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is:

```ml
fun iter 0 f x = x
  | iter n f x = iter (n-1) f (f x);
```

Note: you can replace `f` by `_` at line 1 since `f` does not appear in the resulting expression.

Answer (score 1):

OP code is mixing curried function notation with tuple notation. The OP defines a curried function, but then passes a tuple to it in the recursive call. There are two obvious solutions: decide whether curried notation or tuple notation is desired, and use that consistently.

With tuple notation `iter` takes a *tuple* containing the arguments, i.e., here `iter` really only takes one argument which is a data type that contains parameters. That is, tuple `iter` has type: `fn : int * ('a -> 'a) * 'a -> 'a`

```
fun iter (0, _, x) = x
  | iter (n, f, x) = iter(n-1, f, f x);
```

The above could be expressed a bit differently, e.g., `iter((n-1), f, (f x))`, or `iter((n-1), f, f(x))`.

With the curried notation `iter` takes a single `int` argument and returns a function that takes a function argument, returning a function which takes an argument matching the passed function. That is, curried `iter` has type `fn : int -> ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a`.

```
fun iter 0 _ x = x
  | iter n f x = iter (n-1) f (f x);
```

The tuple version and the curried version are two distinctly different situations. With the tuple version, if you pass fewer than three "arguments" you have a type error, e.g., something like:

```
- iter(2, double);
stdIn:1.2-1.17 Error: operator and operand do not agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: int * ('Z -> 'Z) * 'Z
  operand:         'Y[INT] * (int -> int)
  in expression:
    iter (2,double)
```

The problem is that the tuple version expects a tuple argument that contains three fields. Passing a tuple with fewer than three fields violates this expectation.

But with the curried version, if you pass fewer than three arguments you have a partial function application:

```
- val doubleTwice = iter 2 double;
val doubleTwice = fn : int -> int
- doubleTwice 3;
val it = 12 : int
- doubleTwice 5;
val it = 20 : int
```

Here, passing only two arguments to the curried `iter`, one of them a `double` function that doubles an `int`, returns a function that doubles an input value twice. Curried functions can be very useful, and you need to learn the difference between these two styles.